# Measure tcp-connection speed

Tags: c, sockets, unix, time, tcp

I want to write simple unix-application that measures tcp-connection speed. 
So I have:

- server listens on specified port, accepts connections and measures speed
- client sends messages (continuously)

I thought that measurement on server is somthing like this:

```
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);
size = recv(csocket_fd, buf, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &end);
```

but it seems like it's wrong way.

any suggestions?

Comment: This seems inconsistent, since it may return very quickly if data has already been received and held in buffers just waiting to be deliverd to you, or very slowly if you must wait for data to be sent at a time of the remote system's choosing.  To solve your problem first you'll have to decide what "speed" means.  For example, you could time the entire process of transferring a large file.  But realize that TCP is designed for reliability, not speed - especially not speed in the sense of low latency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the server, when you receive the first data from the client, record the current time to a variable.

Also on the server, whenever you receive data from the client, add the number of bytes received to a counter variable.

Then at any time you want, you can calculate the cumulative average bytes-per-second speed of the connection by calculating (total_bytes_received)/(current_time - first_data_received_time);   (Watch out for a potential divide by zero if current_time and first_data_received_time are equal!)

If you want to do something more elaborate, like a running average over the last 10 seconds, that's a little more involved, but computing the cumulative average is pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a few assignments in networking and one thing that i noticed it is that it wouldn't work the way you are trying to. We have to complete a send-receive for the server to receive again and there are other factors that prevent us from doing it ... from MTUs to buffer sizes etc. I have used is [netperf](http://www.netperf.org/netperf/) to benchmark bandwidths before[is this the speed you are talking about ?]. The code is open source.

Comment: I am really sorry ... i can't seem to comment on the question post .. had to put it as an answer